# Sum of two columns in Entity Linq

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I am struggling to translate a query from sql to entity linq. My select should be the Sum of prodhis.stock_units_free minus the Sum of prodhis.stock_units_it

can anyone point me in the right direction?

This is what I have

```
Dim res As Integer = (From it In rmis.product_detail Join prodhis In rmis.PRODUCT_HISTORY On it.SKU_ID Equals prodhis.SKU_ID _
                         Where prodhis.WEEK_SELECTOR = cws AndAlso
                         it.POS_CODE = ItemID AndAlso
                         prodhis.BRANCH_ID = 23
                         'Stuck Here:
Select (sum(prodhis.STOCK_UNITS_FREE) - sum(prodhis.STOCK_UNITS_IT))
```

Sum is not declared error....

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change your select to:

```
Select prodhis.STOCK_UNITS_FREE - prodhis.STOCK_UNITS_IT).Sum();
```